# Using RJDBC to execute an Oracle stored procedure with return cursor

Tags: r, jdbc

I need to execute a stored procedure on Oracle database which returns a cursor.  I need to execute this in R with JDBC.  Has anyone been in this situation and found a way to make it work?

I think the actual code should just be as follows:

`var rc refcursor
execute myproc(:rc)
print rc`

But I can't make this work using RJDBC with Oracle.  I am trying to use the `dbGetQuery` function without any luck.

Any ideas would be really appreciated.  And yes, I'm stuck having to use the procedure with result set return object.   Yuk!